# Is conversion operator for generic struct legal?

Tags: c#, generics, struct

Question is: Is conversion operator for generic struct a viable option or just an under-defined corner case?

My specific use-case situation here is that I have a collection of structs to represent physical SI unit types (with explicit operators for each one and conversion operators between them). It worked all fine until new requirement presented itself to make generic 3d vectors for them + with conversion operators to support readable arithmetic syntax (`(m)1.3 + (km)0.041`).

But. **CS0556** tells me that `"conversion must convert to or from enclosing type"` - which is all fine until one realizes that's not even possible for generic structs. Because while conversions between `VECTOR<km>` and `VECTOR<T>` may be technically legal to define - are pretty much useless if you don't know both types here.

```
public struct VECTOR<T>
{
    public double3 Value;

    // I wanted to define all possible conversions this way, but suddenly:
    // (CS0556) user-defined conversion must convert to or from enclosing type
    public static implicit operator VECTOR<m> ( VECTOR<km> val ) => new VECTOR<m>{ Value = val.Value * 1e+3 };
}
```

I know this can be refactored into classes - yet I need this to stay as struct. And conversion can be refactored into methods - but operators are most math-like and readable and I want to keep them.
Looks like a dead end. Any thoughts, ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, operators for generic types has to be generic as well, simply because it either has to take in or return the enclosing type, as the error message says. You can create an operator that takes in or outputs `VECTOR<T>`, but you can't declare the concrete operators.

Comment: You can, however, create extension methods.